# Unable to find type [System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator] error in Powershell

Tags: powershell, assemblies

I got a problem, which I haven't been able to solve even though I checked many resources. I might have missed a very important step since I am not a Windows developer and I have very little knowledge about powershell.

Here is my PS versiontable.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                      
----                           -----                                                                                                      
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1018                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                    
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1018                                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                            
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                        
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                        
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I want to add dynamically populated value array for one of the flag of my function (like COMPREPLY in bash).

I have written the following example based on the sources I checked online.

```
class GetProfiles : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator
{
    [String[]] GetValidValues()
    {
        $Paths = "D:\Profiles"
        $Profiles = ForEach ($Path in $Paths)
        {
            if (Test-Path $Path)
            {
                (Get-ChildItem $Path).BaseName
            }
        }
        return [string[]] $Profiles
    }
}

function global:Activate()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [ValidateSet([GetProfiles])]
        [string]$Profile="",
    )

    Write-Host $Profile
}
```

But my code produces this error.

`At D:\projects\activate.ps1:40 char:20
+ ... SoundNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unable to find type [System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator].
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound`

I have the following dll and I tried to add it at the top of the script with `Add-Type -Path`, didn't work :/.

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll`

Any ideas? Would you mind putting me in a right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

that is only available in ps6+. this page ...

IValidateSetValuesGenerator Interface (System.Management.Automation) | Microsoft Docs
— https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.ivalidatesetvaluesgenerator?view=pscore-6.0.0

... makes that pretty clear. [*grin*] plus, when you select Windows Powershell, it shows this ...

> The requested page is not available for Windows PowerShell SDK 1.1.0. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

Comment: lame really :/ thought I had the latest, turns out 6 core is different. Here they are for people https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.1.3 , Thanks Lee!

Comment: @verte - you are most welcome! please read up about what ps6 & winps5.1 are ... they are not really "version 5.1 upgrades is to ps6". one is the stable, _widely_ supported on windows version for _windows_ ... the other is the new, not very widely compatible with windows servers _cross platform version_. [*grin*]

Comment: this is exactly what I am figuring out at the moment. I wonder at the same time, If I was in say PS version 2 or something, wouldn't providing dynamic ValidateSet be possible? Assuming PS (and its older versions) would have different way of providing such feature.

Comment: @verte - i don't know anything at all about that. [*blush*] i vaguely understand a very small amount of the dynamic parameters ... you may want to ask a new question on just exactly what you want. perhaps over at superuser?

Comment: Totally, I got another bottleneck so to speak anyway. Though, thanks a lot for your time, much appreciated!